# How to make a gap in tablayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using angroid support tabLayout for tabs. Designer sent me new design, where part of button overlaps the tab layout and at this point tablayout should have a gap http://joxi.ru/EA41vVBCyRKvrb

Comment: Can you add a tab with blank text as the label and then disable the tab from being selected ?

Comment: @apelsoczi tabs are scrollable, so that will not work